Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS boots with black screen on live usb
I have turned off secure boot and when I try to boot from usb, it shows the try or install Ubuntu, Ubuntu(safe graphics) but when I click either of them, the computer boots to a black screen. I hear a sound effect after some seconds but it still shows a black screen.
My pc's bios mode is uefi and I'm using a nvidia GTX 730.
Ps: I know nothing about Linux and this is my first time using it.

Try a Live Session
